# Grid Editor Renderer

Tags: extjs, editor, render

The problem I am facing is with a grid which allows RowEditing.

The data in my grid comes from a DataBase and I render the data according to the needs, like changing the date to d.m.y format because the date I recieve is in UTC format.

Can someone please help me figure out how to **maintain this rendering at the time of editing** because while editing it changes again to UTC format.